# NodeJS async function result

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, nestjs, asteriskami

Ok. I'm trying do some app. I'm use nodejs + nestjs. I want do request on some url and my controller must connect to Asterisk over AMI and get some info (e.g QueueStatus members). I use async asterisk-ami-client

I've some controller

In console log i watch true value, but how i can return it as result getExtStatus?

```
@Controller("ami")
export class AmiController {

  constructor(private amiService: AmiService) {
  }

  @Get("ext_status")
  async getExtStatus(@Body() user: User) {
    let client = new AmiClient();
    client.connect(user.wssServer.amiuser, user.wssServer.amisecret, {host: user.wssServer.server, port:5038})
      .then(amiConnection => {
        client
          .on('event', event => {
            if (event.Event === "QueueMember" && event.Name === user.extensionNumber){
              console.log(event.Status)
              return event.Status
            }
          })
      })
      .action({Action: "QueueStatus"})

  }

}
```

UPD: I've partical solve my issue, but this solution work once. If send some request few time he is return correctly data. Any idea?

```
@Controller("ami")
export class AmiController {
  private my_field = null;
  constructor(private amiService: AmiService) {
  }
  @Get("ext_status")
  async getExtStatus(@Body() user: User) {
    let client = new AmiClient();
    client.connect(user.wssServer.amiuser, user.wssServer.amisecret, { host: user.wssServer.server, port: 5038 })
      .then(amiConnection => {
        client
          .on("event", event => {
            if (event.Event === "QueueMember" && event.Name === user.extensionNumber) {
              this.my_field = event;
            }
          })
          .action({ Action: "QueueStatus" });
      });
    return this.getField();
  }

  getField() {
    const r = this.my_field;
    return { message: r };
  }
}
```

Comment: it isn't possible to return value before it exists. The proper solution would be to return a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. This code works fine

```
@Injectable()
export class AmiService {

    private extensionInfo = null;
    constructor(@InjectModel(User) private userRepository: typeof User) {}
    
    async getExtensionStatus(user: User) {
        let client = new AmiClient();
        client.connect(user.wssServer.amiuser, user.wssServer.amisecret, {host: user.wssServer.server, port: 5038})
            .then(amiConnection => {
                client
                    .on("event", event => {
                        if (event.Event === "QueueMember" && event.Name === user.extensionNumber) {
                            this.extensionInfo = event
                        }
                    })
                    .action({Action: "QueueStatus"});
            });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (this.extensionInfo != null) {
                    const r = this.extensionInfo;
                    this.extensionInfo = null;
                    resolve(r)
                } else {
                    resolve({message: "Extension not found"})
                }

            }, 1000)
        })
    }
}
```